# Troubles with Task getting Task result (cannot implicitly convert System.Threading.Task.Task to string[])

Tags: c#

```
Task t = new Task(() => grabber.grab(link));

var x = Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));

if (x.Result != null)
{
    // error cannot implicitly convert System.Threading.Task.Task  to string[]
    string[] result = x.Result; 
    foreach (string item in result)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The function grab is totally synchronous and returns a string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking the result from the `x` Task, which is the Task that can be either the same as `t` or the result of `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))` (provided you `await` it). You should be able to get the Result from `t` instead:

```
Task<string[]> t = new Task<string[]>(() => grabber.grab(link));
//   ^^^^^^^^  also defining what the t.Result should contain    

var x = await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
if (x == t){ // make sure that Task.WhenAny returned the t Task
{
    string[] result = t.Result; // get t's Result, not x
    foreach (string item in result)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Created a small reproducable example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPF1sf)

Comment: Totally forgot I need to put what a task returns thanks